# How can I make text in dialog windows selectable (for copying)?

Tags: gui, gtk, qt, dialog, copy-and-paste

Well, I mean more *all* windows rather than just dialog windows, but I can't think of a better term to start pointing in the direction of what I mean.

To be more concrete:

```bash
kdialog              --title 'title'     --inputbox  'I want to be able to select this text for copying'     # eg with qt  
zenity   --entry     --title 'title'     --text      'I want to be able to select this text for copying'     # eg with gtk
```

But to be clear, I don't mean I just want to make it so that the text is selectable in *those* specific windows that I create,
but rather, I'm looking for something like a system setting I can change so that text is selectable by default in *any* window on my system.

(I'm guessing there'll be two separate solutions for qt and gtk apps, although ideally I wish I could just make *ALL* text in *ANY* window selectable.)

This is an *extremely* annoying problem that I run into all the time,
but just to give the most recent example:
I'm using the `timeshift-gtk` gui,
and under button-"Settings">tab-"Filters">button-"Summary", there's a big list of all the exclude/include patterns...
which I can't select and copy.

I'm using kubuntu 20.04.3, but if I remember right I had the same problem in gnome on ubuntu too.

Comment: `zenity --entry --title 'title' --text='help text' --entry-text='I can select this text for copying' --width=400`

Comment: `zenity --info --title 'title' --text='I can select this text for copying' --width=400`